# python3 uuid to base64.urlsafe encode and decode mismatch

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a problem getting a base64-encoded uuid to match the original uuid.

Here is the code:

```
import base64, uuid

def uuid2slug(uuidstring):
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes).decode("utf-8").rstrip('=\n').replace('/', '_')

def slug2uuid(slug):
    return uuid.UUID(bytes=base64.urlsafe_b64decode((slug + '==').replace('_', '/')))

uid = uuid.uuid1()
urlslug = uuid2slug(uid)
urluid = slug2uuid(urlslug)

print(uid)
print(urlslug)
print(urluid)
```

This returns a mismatch in the uuid's first column:

```
cfe71fa2-7d39-11e7-9264-000c29023711
z-cg7H05EeeSZAAMKQI3EQ
cfe720ec-7d39-11e7-9264-000c29023711
```

Any thoughts?

This is using Python 3.5.3

Comment: you re-create the uuid not passing the uuidstring

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem in your code was that you were not using the argument you passed to the function, `uuidstring`.

Also note that you are using the `urlsafe` encoding and decoding libraries, so you don't need to replace the slashes yourself.

For reference, a Base64 value can be defined with the following regex, `^[A-Za-z0-9+/]+={0,2}$`, where `+` and `-` are the only non-alphanumeric symbols, and `=` is only used for padding. The URL encoding is explained in the [Base64 (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) article,

> the '+' and '/' characters of standard Base64 are respectively replaced by '-' and '_', so that using URL encoders/decoders is no longer necessary

Long story short, the correct version of your functions, without the redundant calls to `replace` are:

```
def uuid2slug(uuidstring):
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuidstring.bytes).decode("utf-8").strip('=')

def slug2uuid(slug):
    return uuid.UUID(bytes=base64.urlsafe_b64decode(slug+'=='))
```

If you run your code a couple of times, you will find hyphens and underscores, and no slashes.

E.g.

```
471f8fc4-5ec5-11ed-9645-06ca5f5b4308
Rx-PxF7FEe2WRQbKX1tDCA
471f8fc4-5ec5-11ed-9645-06ca5f5b4308

ac74e9fe-5ec6-11ed-b5e7-06ca5f5b4308
rHTp_l7GEe215wbKX1tDCA
ac74e9fe-5ec6-11ed-b5e7-06ca5f5b4308
```